# CSS IE Compatibility Issues

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm new to programming in general, especially CSS.  I am currently working on a new website for train enthusiasts.  I'm doing it from scratch so that I can get some experience in HTML, CSS, PHP, MySQL, etc.

Anyways, I've run into a problem.  I've searched Google for a solution, but haven't been able to find one.  My CSS seems to be compatible with every web browser on the market EXCEPT Internet Explorer.  I don't really know how to explain the problem unless you check it out for yourself.  It's as if my header and left menu are the only styled elements, but my content and right menu are pushed to the right and not styled.  Check [this link](http://www.railsightings.com/) in IE and another browser respectively.  You'll see the difference.

So my question is this: How do I fix it?  I know it must be an IE bug since it works in every other browser, but I don't know what it could be!  If I need to post my CSS script, let me know.  Thanks in advance for any help you guys can offer!

Comment: Validate your HTML using the W3C online tool.  IE will be much happier.

Comment: Good 'ol IE Always heard it doesn't like alot of things

Comment: i checked out on chrome and IE8, doesnt look different to me. What exactly is the issue? you can always try to set a reset css in your header. This will remove any default paddings or margins that are set.

Comment: show your code, please. And you have an empty line before your `<!doctype>`

Comment: @iight is 100% right.  IE will have serious rendering issues if `doctype` is not the very first thing in the file.

Answer (score 1):

In your style sheet you have a superfluous `width:100%` on a div element (block level elements naturally have a width that fills their container).  IE is interpreting this 100% as that of `#container`.  You can correct the styling issue in IE7 (theoretically) by removing this `width:100%` at line 119 of styles.css.  I theorize that this is cased by how IE7 interprets `display:inline-block`

I must warn you, however, that ensuring compatibility with IE 7 and lower is a major pain in the arse and totally not worth it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are you using to test it?? I checked it on Firefox, IE9,8 and 7. looks fine on IE8 and IE9. While there are few issues on 7. You could use conditional commenting to fix issues in 7.
create a new css file specially for IE7 and then
use a code like the following in your header

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

now play around with ie7.css till things look better. The good thing about this method is you can fix issues in IE without interfering with other browser rendering. You could also use "ietester"  and debug bar to determine what exactly is wrong. im not able to find the exact link right now but google should help.

You could read more about conditional commenting here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html